# SVG in child component template

Tags: svg, angular

AngularJS 1.X has the `templateNamespace` property on the object returned by directives. This one can be set to `svg`.
But I can't find a way to set the template namespace in AngularJS 2.

When I try such kind of code, nothing is rendered ( [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/scrMsHvLKjwCr5Z3I1Qi?p=preview) ):

```
@Component({
   selector : "my-app",
   template : `
      <svg width="100" height="100">
         <circle> </circle>
      </svg>
   `,
   directives : [CircleComponent]
})
export class MyAppComponent { }

@Component({
  selector : "circle",
  template : `
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red"> </circle>
  `
})
export class CircleComponent { }
```

We can see that the circle svg tag is inside the circle component tag name. Probably the reason why it can not work. Since `replace : true` can't be used anymore, it's not a solution too.

Sidenote :
writting a circle with a self closing tag like this gives an error.
`<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red"/>`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about namespaces, you add the namespace prefix to the element tag:

```
template: `<svg:circle ...></svg:circle>`
```

...then Angular2 will use that namespace for that element and its child elements in the template.  And note that although you can do the same for an svg element tag itself:

```
template: `<svg:svg ...></svg:svg>`
```

...it is not necessary in this case and is usually not done.

Now, note this second problem:  You are using "circle" as a selector, which expands from

```
<circle></circle>
```

to

```
<circle>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red"></circle>
</circle>
```

which is not valid SVG and will not render.  (It also looks like it would recurse, but fortunately Angular doesn't seem to do that.)

Instead, use an attribute selector with some new name:

```
selector: "[my-circle]"
```

and a template like so:

```
template: `<g my-circle></g>`
```

Comment: I tried the same in angular 2 ,but it doesnt render at all.do we need to add any changes